# Controller able to access posted data in update() but not in store() under Laravel 7. Routing problem or not?

Tags: laravel

I can't seem access posted data in my `store()`-method in Laravel. A very simple cms-system of quotes under Laravel 7 works well to destroy and updatete quote-entries, but I cannot store new ones.

I've traced the problem to the `store()`-method not getting access to the posted data in `$request`.

In my **`QuotesController.php`**:

```
print_r("request-title:".$request->input('title'));
```

gives me nothing in `store()`, even though `update()` works fine. A look at the request (`print_r("<code> $request </code>");`) tells me that the `store()` does not have an empty `$request`:

```
POST /quotes/store HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-us Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 47 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Cookie:
```

My **`QuotesController.php`** contains

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Quote;
class QuotesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        print_r("request-title (store):".$request->input('title'));die();
    }
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        print_r("request-title (update):".$request->input('title'));die();
    }
```

In my **`view`**, I make the form to **create** like so:

```
<form action="store" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
</form>
```

I suspect that my troubles derive from bad routing. To look for routing-errors, I typed out each route explicitly in **`web.php`**:

```
Route::get('/quotes/populate', 'QuotesController@populate')->name('quotes.populate');
Route::get('/quotes/{id}', 'QuotesController@show')->name('quotes.show');
Route::get('/quotes/create', 'QuotesController@create')->name('quotes.create');
Route::post('/quotes/store', 'QuotesController@store')->name('quotes.store');
Route::get('/quotes/{id}/edit', 'QuotesController@edit')->name('quotes.edit');
Route::post('/quotes/{id}/update', 'QuotesController@update')->name('quotes.update');
Route::get('/quotes/{id}/destroy', 'QuotesController@destroy')->name('quotes.destroy');
Route::get('/quotes', 'QuotesController@index')->name('quotes.index');
```

In `QuotesController::update()`, meanwhile, all is well, and `$request->input('title')` contains the posted data.

Where am I going wrong? Why doesn't my posted data appear in `store()` as it does in `update()`

Comment: Your `<input>` has no name attribute. That's why there is no 'title' in the request. Try again with `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">`

Comment: `<input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="title">`

Comment: Ohhh. Dear me. The corona-time home-confinement has fried my brain! :( Sorry and thanks. I'm just jumping from CakePHP to Larvel, and was confused by routing this morning, I defined an id-pattern llike `Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');`, but was so sure that this stuff had to do with Laravel and not my sloppiness. I'll go and read a book now: Cheers guys.

Comment: If that pattern you defined was for a model's id, you're better off using route model binding. And when you doubt your own routes, try running `php artisan r:l` to get every single one displayed. You can add `--help` for some additional commands. As for dumping variables in the controller, you can use the `dd($var1, $var2, $var3, ...)` helper (dump and die) or the `dump($var1, $var2, $var3, ...)` helper.